# Are there any characters beyond utf32 dataset

Tags: utf-32

Are there or could there be some old or new characters beyond the **utf32** dataset?

Is there a bigger dataset?

Just a random question..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about programming.

Comment: Thanks buddy, go  for it!

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't a judgement on you, or whether the question is _interesting_, it's just that this site has a particular focus, as set out in the [help], and I'm not sure this fits it.

Comment: Anybody can make up a new dataset. *You* can make up a new dataset. So there, it's done.

Comment: Its not about making new dataset, but more chars. Is utf32 constantly updated with new chars appearing or going trought some process before that?

Comment: There is a process for adding characters to utf32. But anybody can just make up a system that is outside Unicode. (For example, Klingon script.)